# Rails - stringify_key error when attempting to change a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button that changes a boolean value to deactivate an object rather than delete it. It works, however when I attempt to apply styling to it, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/coins/1/flop":String
```

I understand that stringify_keys is attempting to convert symbols to string but I'm not sure how it applies to this situation or how to fix it.

```
<div class="coin-container__coin-header-container" id="coin-hdr">
  <img class="" src='<%= @img_url_ %>' />
  <h2><%= @coin.currency_name %></h2>
  <% coin_change_class = "coin-change" %>
  <% @percent_change_1h_ >= 0 ? coin_change_class += ' positive' : coin_change_class += ' negative' %>
  <p class='<%= coin_change_class %>'><%= @percent_change_1h_ %>%</p>

  <div class="coin-update-buttons">     
    <% if can? :update, @coin %>
        <%= link_to edit_coin_path(@coin), "data-turblinks" => "false" do %>
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, @coin %>
      <%= link_to (@coin.accepted ? true : false), flop_coin_path(@coin), data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this coin?" } do %>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

The flop method in my Coin controller is as follows:

```
def flop
  coin = Coin.find(params[:id])
  coin.accepted = !coin.accepted
  coin.save
  redirect_to coin_path(coin)
end
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Does my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/coins/1/flop":String

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

You are doing it wrong. The correct way to apply styling to the `link_to` which has a name and a block is below.

```
<%= link_to flop_coin_path(@coin), data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this coin?" } do %>
  (@coin.accepted ? true : false) <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
<% end %>
```

Also it is weird to display a *boolean value as a name* to the `link_to`. I would do it like this instead

```
<%= link_to flop_coin_path(@coin), data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this coin?" } do %>
  (@coin.accepted ? "Activate" : "Deactivate") <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
<% end %>
```